# Two Dimensional Array Sorting in Python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a two dimensional array that looks like this:

`intscore[i][0]`: a single integer, integers appear more than once for different `i`

`intscore[i][1]`: a list of 5 integers unigue to this integer case

Index `i` ranges from 0 to a large number.

I want to sort this array such that

`intscore[0][0]`: the smallest integer in the array

`intscore[0][1]`: the list associated with this smallest integer

`intscore[1][0]`: is equal to greater than `intscore[0][0]`

and so on.

I'm new to Python, I've searched the web but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Why would you expect to *find* a solution? You need to *write one!* Where's your attempt, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: The web should be searched later.  It may be worthwhile consulting some of the documentation to fully understanding slicing etc. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard function called sorted, https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting
that is very simple to use, in your case you would simply do,

```
sorted(2dArray)
```